# Replace nil with Empty or Error in Combine

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a Combine publisher like this:

```
enum RemoteError: Error {
    case networkError(Error)
    case parseError(Error)
    case emptyResponse
}

func getPublisher(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Entiy, RemoteError> {
    return URLSession.shared
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: RemoteResponse.self, decoder: decoder)
        .mapError { error -> RemoteError in
            switch error {
            case is URLError:
                return .networkError(error)
            default:
                return .parseError(error)
            }
        }
        .map { response -> Entiy in
            response.enitities.last
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

struct RemoteResponse: Codable {
    let enitities: [Entity]
    let numberOfEntries: Int
}

struct Entity {

}
```

By the above setting, the compiler complains because `response.enitities.last` can be nil. The question is can I replace nil with Empty publisher and if not can I replace it with error `emptyResponse` in Combine chain? The first option is preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

If you don't want the publisher to publish anything in case entities is empty, you can use `coampactMap` instead of map:

```
.compactMap { response in
   response.entities.last
}
```

If you would rather publish an error in such a case you can use `tryMap` which allows you to throw an `Error`. You would need `mapError` to come after it:

```
.tryMap { response in
    guard let entity = response.entities.last else {
        throw RemoteError.emptyResponse
    }
    return entity
}
.mapError { error -> RemoteError in
    switch error {
    case is URLError:
        return .networkError(error)
    case is DecodingError:
        return .parseError(error)
    default:
        return .emptyResponse
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: With iOS 13 and Combine first version it complains that you should return Entity instead of Entity? even with CompactMap. I know it sounds weird, but it's the issue.

Comment: Weir compactMap has not changed since iOS 13, you could try something like that to be more explicit:  `.compactMap { response -> Entity? in
    guard let entity = response.entities.last else { return nil }
    return entity
}`

Answer (score 3):

You need a *flat* map in order to map to another *publisher*:

```
.flatMap {
    $0.enitities.last.publisher
}
```

`Optional` has a convenient [`publisher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/3650088-publisher) property that gives you a publisher that publishes only that value if the value is not nil, and an empty publisher if it is nil. This is only available in iOS 14+. If you are targeting a lower version, you need to do something like:

```
.flatMap { (response) -> AnyPublisher<Entity, Never> in
    if let last = response.entities.last {
        return Just(last).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return Empty(completeImmediately: true).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard Huh, the explicit type might be upsetting it. See the edit.

Comment: $0.enitities.last.publisher is only available for iOS 14

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard You can add an `if @available` check, and see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from @Sweeper, Here edit with below iOS 14.0

```
.setFailureType(to: NSError.self)
.flatMap { (response) -> AnyPublisher<Entity, Never> in
if let last = response.entities.last {
    return Just(last).eraseToAnyPublisher()
} else {
    return Empty(completeImmediately: true).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

NSError -> will be error type which you are returning

Happy coding